# how to create a python program to make passwords using for and while

Tags: python

Hello i am trying to create a small code that receives password attempts for a number of times (3) , and if the password is wrong , the user can't try again .

can you please tell me why my code is not giving me the expected results i want?

the results it is giving me is a loop that never ends to ask for a try again ; while te results i desire is a loop that ends after 3 trials only . 
"i would love to keep in the while loop"

thank you very much

my code is

```
password=''    
for i in range(1,3):
        if i<3:
           while password!='daniel':
                    password=input("enter the password:")
                    if password=="daniel":
                        print('your logged in ')
                    else:
                        print('try again ')
        else:
            print("number of trials done")

`
```

Comment: Not a solution, but when you use `for i in range(1,3)`, including `if i<3:` is redundant. Similarly, `while password!='daniel':` makes `if password=="daniel":` redundant. It might be worth looking into loops, conditions, and the `break` statement again and rewriting this code

Comment: Please explain the "*not working*" part.  What do you expect and what you actually get?

Comment: @G.Anderson - you may want to rethink some parts of your comments. `while` loop wouldn't end the very moment its condition becomes false.

Comment: @G.Anderson i have re-edited my question , if you can help me. thank you

Answer (score 1):

When you run this code you should get the error: `NameError: name 'password' is not defined`. This is because Python runs through your code line by line, and when it gets to the line `while password!='daniel'` it has no idea what `password` is because it hasn't yet been told, and so just stops running.

To fix errors like this you just need to first tell Python that `password` is going to be a variable which will store text. You can initialise the variable with empty text like so: `password=''`, this must be put anywhere before the line that causes the error.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(3):
  password=input("enter the password:")
  if password=="daniel":
      print('your logged in ')
      break
  elif i < 2:
      print('try again ')
else:
  print('Number trials exceeded')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0,3):
    if i<3:
        password = input("enter the password:\n")
        if password=="daniel":
            print('your logged in ')
            break
        else:
            print('try again ')
            continue
    else:
        print("number of trials done")
```

Or

```
password=''
i = flag = 0
while password!='daniel'and  i<3:
    password=input("enter the password:\n")
    if password=="daniel":
        print('your logged in ')
        flag=1
    else:
        print('try again ')
    i +=1

if flag==0:
    print("number of trials done")
```

Comment: thank you but i would love to use the while loop to see , how it would work , if it is possible .

Comment: @KaberaDavid, I have edited the post with while loop solution

Answer (score 0):

Using both for loop and nested while loop makes the number of trials has no end. In addition, you should assign the variable `password` before you add it to the condition, or you can use `while True` and `break` instead.

```py
counter = 0
while True:
    if counter < 3:
        counter += 1
        password = input('Enter the password: ')
        if password == 'daniel':
            print("You're logged in")
            break
        else:
            print('Try again')
    else:
        print('Number of trials is done. Please try again later.')
        break
```

Or you can do it using for loop.

```py
for i in range(0,4):
    if i < 3:
        password = input('Enter the password: ')
        if password == 'daniel':
            print("You're logged in")
            break
        else:
            print('Try again')
    else:
        print('Number of trials is done. Please try again later.')
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem with you code is you are using `password` with out intializing it. second the while loop will run forever unless the correct password is given. third even with the correct password given the while loop has a chance to restart for another 2 rounds

Here is an alternative

```
for trial in range(3):
    password=input("enter the password:")
    if password=="daniel":
        print('your logged in ')
        break
    elif trial == 2:
        print("number of trials done")
    else:
        print('try again ')
    trial = trial + 1
```